# IE not updating drop down selection dispaly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have 3 drop downs with angular scope array bound to it. When I update the model one drop down shows the value as selected, but the other two not updating the dispaly. Actually the item is selected but the the dropdown shows a blank item. I am using AngularJS v1.2.2 and IE11
In chrome it is working fine. The selection issue happens only when using select ng-options with filters

```
   
    //$scope.Areas is bound to dropdown and $scope.A.Area is the ng-model to Area dropdown, working fine
    $scope.A.Area = $scope.Areas.firstOrDefault(function (x) {
    return x.AreaID === $scope.RespondentAreaID;
    });

    //$scope.Regions is bound to Region dropdown and $scope.A.Region is the ng-model to Region dropdown, not updating the dropdown diaplay in IE
    $scope.A.Region = $scope.Regions.firstOrDefault(function (x) {
    return x.RegionID === $scope.A.RespondentRegionID;
    });

    // There is no countries list in the scope like $scope.Areas or $scope.Regions
    // Countries are stored as navigational property with Region, so to populate the 
    // countries use the selected Region.Countries, not working in IE
    if ((($scope.A.Region || {}).Countries || []).length) {
    $scope.A.Country = $scope.A.Region.Countries.firstOrDefault(function (x) {
    return x.CountryID === $scope.RespondentCountryID;
    });
```

Comment: Having the exact same issue with any group of select dropdowns. Seems to work if you try selecting the value in the dropdown again. Ex: Select the month in a group of 3 date dropdowns, try to select the day but it just shows the first option in the select dropdown. Try to select a value again, and it works. Angular 1.2.0-rc.2 with IE11. Take it you haven't found a solution in the last couple days?

Comment: Thanks areynolds, I found a solution, it will select the value if we changes the text of dropdown. Once the dropdown values are set  Found this solution in stackoverflow, but dont remember the link // This is an IE fix for not updating the section of dropdowns which has ng-options with filters
   angular.forEach($("select"), function (currSelect) {
    currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].text += " ";
   });

Answer (score 0):

Adding couple of lines the following places (marked in bold) in render function of the selectDirective in angular.js worked fine for me.  I am looking if there is any other possible solution other than patching angularJS or the forEach given below?

```
            if (existingOption.label !== option.label) {
              lastElement.text(existingOption.label = option.label);
              **lastElement.attr('label', existingOption.label);**
            }
```

and

```
              (element = optionTemplate.clone())
                  .val(option.id)
                  .attr('selected', option.selected)
                  .text(option.label);
              **element.attr('label', option.label);**
```

The issue was the label attribute of HTMLOptionElement is not the same as the text attribute if label is blank in IE.

This can be seen verified by adding the following code after the screen has loaded and looking at the web console of FF and IE to see the difference.  If you uncomment the last line where the label is set to text it works fine.  Alternatively patch angular.js as above.

```
// This is an IE fix for not updating the section of dropdowns which has ng-options with filters
angular.forEach($("select"), function (currSelect) {
    console.log("1.text ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].text);
    console.log("1.label ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].label);
    //console.log("1.innerHTML ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
    //console.log("1.textContent ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].textContent);
    //console.log("1.cN.data ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].data);
    //console.log("1.cN.nodeValue ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    //console.log("1.cN.textContent ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].textContent);
    //console.log("1.cN.wholeText ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].wholeText);
    //console.log("1. ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex], "\n");

    //currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].label = "xyz";
    //currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].label = currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].text;
});
```